# How to do arithmetic in bash when the operator is stored in a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

```
add=+

echo "$((1{$add}2))"
```

If I write 1+2 it outputs 3, but when I store the + sign in a variable called "add" and then use it in place of + operator, it just outputs it as if it was a string. How can I use the variable and still make it output 3?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: It should be `$((1${add}2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the code is wrong and should not print anything but an error.
What you should do is write the variable as `${add}`, not `{$add}`.